# Reproducing downsampling effect on guitar tone

Tags: guitar, tone, downsampling

I've noticed if I downsample my classical guitar recordings from 44100Hz to 8000Hz, the result is a bassy vintage electric guitar sound, which I really like in some songs of mine.

I know because of the sampling theorem, the downsampling involves cutting all frequencies above 8000/2=4000Hz. I did the same on the original 44100Hz signal, applying a low pass filter at 4000Hz with 48db steepness (maximum allowed by the Audacity software I am using), but could not recreate the same downsampled tone with just this.

I used Audacity Spectral Selection and then the spectral delete plugin to delete all frequencies above 4kHz, just like downsampling at 8kHz does but without loosing quality. This is a great way to simulate a guitar pickup if you record your classical guitar with a good external condenser mic like I do.

Do you know what else is going on downsampling? Or how can I find out out? I would like to have the same altered tone I get with downsampling, but without loosing sound quality, keeping the signal sampled at cd quality.

Comment: Did you apply the EQ curve before downsampling, or just hard downsample it?

Comment: Are you downsampling in Audacity or something else?

Answer (score 1):

1. Audacity (and probably other resampling algorithms as well) use filters that are steeper than 48 dB/octave. The difference might be audible.
2. As the goal of filtering in resampling is to cut frequencies above the new fs/2, the filter frequency needs to be placed a bit below fs/2. Again, the difference might be audible.
3. Concerning the sentence in your answer *"spectral delete plugin to delete all frequencies above 4kHz"* note that no filter is perfect, and every filter comes with some limitations and compromises. There is no way to *delete* all components in a given frequency range, though good plugins these days certainly can do a very decent job. I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.